# Archlinux Samba 4.5.1 - session setup failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

Tags: linux, active-directory, archlinux, samba

I was use samba as member of AD for years. Now Samba 4.5.1 dont allow users enter shared folders.

Test:

```
smbclient -L cz2 -U administrator
Enter administrator's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

wbinfo, getent, net ads info working fine

```
**wbinfo -u**
administrator
krbtgt
guest
```

getent passwd

```
ntp:x:87:87:Network Time Protocol:/var/lib/ntp:/bin/false
git:x:996:996:git daemon user:/:/bin/bash
administrator:*:10500:10513:Administrator:/srv/samba/users/administrator:/bin/fail
krbtgt:*:10502:10513:krbtgt:/srv/samba/users/krbtgt:/bin/fail
guest:*:10501:10514:Guest:/srv/samba/users/guest:/bin/fail
```

net ads info

```
LDAP server: 10.10.1.2
LDAP server name: cz1.company.local
Realm: COMPANY.LOCAL
Bind Path: dc=COMPANY,dc=LOCAL
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Wed, 09 Nov 2016 16:46:09 CET
KDC server: 10.10.1.2
Server time offset: 0
Last machine account password change: Wed, 09 Nov 2016 16:34:20 CET
```

Testing machine with Windows 2008 server working fine. So Problem is not in Samba AD (CZ1 10.10.1.2)

Log file

```
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.751082,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:178(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [COMPANY]\[administrator]@[CZ2] with the new password interface
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.751106,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:181(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [COMPANY]\[administrator]@[CZ2]
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.781423,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:249(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password: winbind authentication for user [administrator] succeeded
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.781482,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:305(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [administrator] -> [administrator] -> [COMPANY/administrator] succeeded
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.781650,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:509(ntlmssp_sign_reset)
  NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.781671,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.781716,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:509(ntlmssp_sign_reset)
  NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.781731,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.783333,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:430(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-2983937313-3188343367-1241514986-500 -> getpwuid(10500) failed
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.783370,  3] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:316(create_local_nt_token_from_info3)
  Failed to finalize nt token
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.783395,  1] ../source3/smbd/sesssetup.c:290(reply_sesssetup_and_X_spnego)
  Failed to generate session_info (user and group token) for session setup: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.783634,  3] ../source3/smbd/error.c:82(error_packet_set)
  NT error packet at ../source3/smbd/sesssetup.c(293) cmd=115 (SMBsesssetupX) NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.784947,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:246(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (failed to receive smb request)
[2016/11/09 16:51:23.817897,  3] ../source3/lib/util_procid.c:54(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved, problem is in precompiled packages

```
samba-4.5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
smbclient-4.5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
libwbclient-4.5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Use ABS system a makepkg again and heureka it works
I hope, that helps to someone